# Is it faster to access a property file or static constants from a class file?

Tags: java, properties, constants

I develop a webservice application in a tomcat container, I have a lot of properties for the webapp like constants, error messages and so on.

What is the better and faster way to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer, as always, is *profile it*.

In general, this is the sort of micro-optimization that almost certainly won't matter. Feel free to profile it and see, though.

Comment: Agree. Don't focus on optimizing things of which you don't know that they actually cause a performance problem. The only good way to optimize is to measure where the bottlenecks are, and concentrate on improving the code that is the bottleneck.

Comment: +1, profiling is the best way to answer the "faster" part of the question. The "better" part needs analysis/insight, though. :-)

Comment: Profiling is irrelevant -- doing I/O when you would have been fine with plain old constants is never going to be better.

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion - that's true, but do you honestly believe for a single instant that *this* is where a performance bottleneck is at? The time spent asking (and answering) the question would have been better spent finding what is *actually* making the system run slower and working on that.

Comment: Oh, I couldn't agree with that more. I just get tired of saying it over and over and over.

Answer (score 2):

Generally static constants; IO activity will always be slower.

However, hard-coding values means that the app will need to be recompiled if the value has to change. It's your call as a developer as to whether the values will ever need to be changed outside of a software release.

Answer (score 2):

As [Bozho says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722424/is-it-faster-to-access-a-property-file-or-static-constants-from-a-class-file/2722445#2722445), in terms of raw speed, you're going to have trouble beating a `public static final`. But speed isn't everything. If you need to worry about localization at all, for instance, a properties file would probably be better, although you might want to look at a [`ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "contstantValue";`

This makes the compiler inline the value, so you have nothing happening at runtime.

You can also store the values anywhere (.properties file) and load them in a static initializer block.